set X_FORWARDED_PREFIX on Symfony double the prefix for asset and specific html tags (form)
Symfony version(s)
5.4.34
Description
It seems there are a conflict on relative url with X_FORWARDED_PREFIX defined.
How to reproduce
My symfony app respond like this :

In Intranet : http://www3.intranet/sfapp/
In Extranet (reverse proxy) : https://extranet.domain.com/www3/sfapp/

I have override X_FORWARDED variables like this   :
# public/index.php
if(array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER', $_SERVER)) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER'];
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] = 'https';
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] = '443';
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PREFIX'] = '/www3/';
}

# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    trusted_proxies: '127.0.0.1,REMOTE_ADDR'
    trusted_headers: ['x-forwarded-for', 'x-forwarded-host', 'x-forwarded-proto', 'x-forwarded-port', 'x-forwarded-prefix']

In my twig file i have set 2 url like this :
{# templates/admin_login.html.twig #}

{% set login_url = path('admin_login') %}
<form action="{{ login_url }}" method="post" role="form">
...
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ login_url }}">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ url('admin_login') }}">
</form>

I have this :
{# WHY twice www3 here ??? #}
<form action="/www3/www3/sfapp/login" method="post" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" value="/www3/sfapp/login">
    <input type="hidden" value="https://extranet.domain.com/www3/sfapp/login">
</form>

I don't understand why i have twice www3 in form tag  ? I have same issue for assets url...
